# like that of + possessive noun

Tags: comparisons

I came across this sentence:

"His memory was like that of a baby."

I was wondering why the possessive "baby's" wasn't used and why "baby" is acceptable whereas the possessive form is required in this sentence:

"Ian's car was like that of *his*."

Comment: This is a gentle reminder. Most of your questions are better fit for our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). As advised by other users, you need to go there and ask a question. But remember, your deleted question on "conjunction" is off-topic on ELL, too. Do not ask off-topic questions here.

Answer (score 1):

The possessive is acceptable in your examples, in which case they mean

> His memory was like a baby's memory.
> Ian's car was like his car.

However, English accepts the so-called *double possessive* in which this elision doesn't apply:

> She is a friend of my sister's.
> John is a fan of hers.

It's redundant since *of*, *-'s*, and possessive pronouns all signify the genitive, but language isn't necessarily logical.  The form has its use in distinguishing

> A picture of my family

which is a portrait of your relatives and

> a picture of my family's

which is a picture your family owns.

We generally reserve the doubled possessive for human beings, like babies and sisters, but not otherwise.  No one says

> the founder of the country's.